# importing tensorflow results in an API version error after installing sklearn in the same conda environment

Tags: macos, tensorflow

I've installed tensorflow using miniconda and everything worked until I've installed sklearn package on the same enviroment. I've removed sklearn and tried to upgrade numpy but it didn't solve the issue. tensorflow version is 2.10 numpy version is 1.23, numpy_base version is 1.21. the laptop is base m2 macbook air.

Comment: It would be great to include an actual example of the debugging issues for others to reproduce.

Comment: RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

Comment: Please include this as an edit in the main question body, not in the comments.

Comment: You can downgrade numpy to 1.19.5 to see whether it works with Tensorflow .  Please make sure you are following metal plugin instructions from Apple for Tensorflow install.

Comment: Attached metal [plug-in instructions](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin)  for reference .